# SEO friendly URL in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

How do I change the .htaccess in wordpress for this URL:

```
/boom/?cat=Kenmerken&subcat=Mooie_stam&naam=Acer-capillipes#boom
```

to

```
/boom/categorie/subcategorie/name/

RewriteRule ^boom/([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z-]+)/(.*)/?  index.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2&naam=$3 [L]
```

Comment: Have you looked at the Settings -> Permalinks panel in your WordPress dashboard? It's set up to do this for you.

Comment: I tried but with no success

Comment: What is "boom"? Is that supposed to be a tag, post type name, a page ...?

Comment: Boom is the page to open. Boom means tree in Dutch. Website is www.boomkwekerijleemreize.nl